# Winform with Active UI and 1 Thread running in the background

Tags: winforms, c#-4.0

I have a Winforms application that calls CorelDraw via it's API and then does some work on an image before saving it.  I have tried setting this using Threads, BackgroundWorker, and a class that inherited BackgroundWorker but also allow for Thread.Abort.  Every way I have done the work, I continuously run into one of 2 issues.  Either the thread is not run in the background, in which case I am unable to press any buttons on the form because it is frozen or the thread runs in the background but immediately stops processing anything when I hit the first call to CorelDraw.

Are there any alternative solutions? The old way we handled this was by having a watcher WinForm spawn another `Process()` that would do everything in CorelDraw. The process called with Process() saves important information into a .txt file for the parent process to check and if the child works on the same image for too long, the parent calls `Kill()` on it.  So far, this has been a clunky and error prone way to do things, which is why I am looking for a better solution.

Comment: The task can be done using `BackgroundWorker`. Write your time-consiming task in `DoWork` event of component and to start, call `RunWorkerAsync`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Designer Code:

```
namespace Tasks
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // button1
            // 
            this.button1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(41, 43);
            this.button1.Name = "button1";
            this.button1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.button1.TabIndex = 0;
            this.button1.Text = "button1";
            this.button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button1.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button1_Click);
            // 
            // button2
            // 
            this.button2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(131, 43);
            this.button2.Name = "button2";
            this.button2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 23);
            this.button2.TabIndex = 1;
            this.button2.Text = "button2";
            this.button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
            this.button2.Click += new System.EventHandler(this.button2_Click);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(240, 116);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button2);
            this.Controls.Add(this.button1);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Button button2;
    }
}
```

This is the form code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Tasks
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        CancellationTokenSource cts;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(this,"This button still works :)");
        }

        private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            cts = new CancellationTokenSource();

            await CreateTask();
        }

        private async Task CreateTask()
        {
            //Create a progress object that can be used within the task
            Progress<string> mProgress; //you can set this to Int for ProgressBar
            //Set the Action to a function that will catch the progress sent within the task
            Action<string> progressTarget = ReportProgress;
            //Your new Progress with the included action function
            mProgress = new Progress<string>(progressTarget); 

            //start your task
            string result = await MyProcess(mProgress);
        }

        private Task<string> MyProcess(IProgress<string> myProgress)
        {
            return Task.Run(() =>
            {
                //To report Progress back to your UI thread
                myProgress.Report("Starting program now...");
                //Start your Corel Draw program here.
                Process.Start("C:\\WINDOWS\\system32\\notepad.exe").WaitForExit();
                //You can return the Image after your done editing it
                return "Program has been closed";

            }, cts.Token);
        }

        private void ReportProgress(string message)
        {
            //typically to update a progress bar or whatever
            MessageBox.Show(this, message);
        }
    }
}
```

If you create async task you can run your Corel application in the background and then when it is closed it will be finish the task. I added in extra stuff in there like Progress and cts is used to cancel the task in case the parent window is closed.